# Laravel delete all rows related to one another in the same table

Tags: laravel

Here i have `folders` table that contains folder information like name etc. all folder may have some sub folders. when i want to remove the parent folder i need to delete all the sub folders and all sub sub folders under sub folders.

[image]

for example in the picture if i delete folder id 1, it must delete folder id 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 and 10. because all the folders are inside folder id 1.

i think i made you understand.

```
Folder::where('id', $id)->delete();
```

This delete only to folder with the given id, not the sub folders

Thanks all

Comment: If you have performance issue, you should  add cascade delete on the foreign key in your database migration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define deleting in the `Folder` model. I suppose that you also defined the relation

```
public function subfolders() {
    return $this->hasMany(Folder::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

So you should add this to your `Folder` model:

```
public static function boot () {
    parent::boot();

    self::deleting(function ($folder) {
        foreach ($folder->subfolders as $subfolder) {
            $subfolder->delete();
        }
    });
}
```

This will be triggered on delete action and will delete all the subfolders, deleting of each of them will also run this function etc.

Answer (score 0):

easy way you can delete first relation and after that del folder

```
Folder::where('paren_id', $id)->delete();
Folder::where('id', $id)->delete();
```